# Filtering a list in python with many key-value pairs

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like this:

```
commands = [
{'command': "start app", 'action': "monitor", 'max-threshold': True, 'zero-failcount': True, 'started': True, 'stopped': False, 'failed': False},
{'command': "read log", 'action': "monitor", 'max-threshold': False, 'zero-failcount': True, 'started': True, 'stopped': False, 'failed': False},
{'command': "kill app", 'action': "monitor", 'max-threshold': True, 'zero-failcount': True, 'started': True, 'stopped': False, 'failed': False}
]
```

And I would like to filter so that only a few cases are seen in the new list. For example, only those with max-threshold with true, zero-failcount true, etc. How do I do this? I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: show your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

For example, something like:

```
[command for command in commands if command['max-threshold']]
```

Comment: So 1 case for each? Because i would like to check every command, action, monitor, max-threshold, zero-failcount, etc.

Comment: If you need to set multiple conditions that's fine.
For example: 
[command for command in commands if not command['max-threshold'] and command['zero-failcount']]. Anything after the if can be any expression that evaluates to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Use filters 
`b  = list(filter(lambda x: x['max-threshold']==True, a))`

Read more here : http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list of k, v pairs to test for (doesn't have to be list of tuples)

```
hav = [('max-threshold', True), ('zero-failcount', True)]

[d for d in commands if all([d[k] == v for k, v in hav])]
```